# Supposedly to be easy weather forecast probability problem

Tags: probability

I did two attempts at this problem but none of them is correct.

**The problem:** A weather forecaster classifies all days as wet or dry. She estimates that the probability that 1 June next year is wet is 0.4. If any particular day in June is wet, the probability that the next day is wet is 0.6; otherwise the probability that the next day is wet is 0.3. Find the probability that, next year at least one of the first three days of June is wet.

**1st attempt:** Probability of at least one = probability of all 3 are wet - probability none is wet = $0.4\times 0.6\times 0.6-0.6\times0.4\times0.4=0.09$

**2nd attempt:** Probability that 3rd day is wet given 1&2 days are wet = $\frac{0.6\times 0.4\times 0.6}{0.4\times 0.6}=0.6$
Probability that 3rd is not wet given 1&2 days are not wet = $\frac{0.3\times 0.6\times 0.3}{0.6\times 0.3}=0.3$
So, probability of at least one is wet is 0.6-0.3=0.3.

The correct solution is 0.706.

I am wondering where did I make the mistake.
Helps are greatly appreciated, many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probability of at least one = 1 - probability of none.

Probability of none = 0.6 (first is dry) * 0.7(second is dry, given first is dry) * 0.7(third is dry, given second is dry)=0.294

Comment: Thanks! ah yes, should have thought about this more carefully.